# how to add an extra delimeter to jquery ui autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a local array for autocomplete which works well.

How do I add 'space' as a delimeter to "tagify" the string that is not from the source array. So far it only works with comma ", "

I'm using stock code from the jquery ui site.

```
                function split( val ) {
                  return val.split( /,\s*/ );
                }
                function extractLast( term ) {
                  return split( term ).pop();
                }

                $( "#create-post__search-field--tags" )
                  // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
                  .bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
                    if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                        $( this ).autocomplete( "instance" ).menu.active ) {
                      event.preventDefault();
                    }
                  })
                  .autocomplete({
                    minLength: 0,
                    source: function( request, response ) {
                      // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                      response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                        availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
                    },
                    focus: function() {
                      // prevent value inserted on focus
                      return false;
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                      var terms = split( this.value );
                      // remove the current input
                      terms.pop();
                      // add the selected item
                      terms.push( ui.item.value );
                      // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                      terms.push( "" );
                      this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                      return false;
                    }
```

I would prefer not using 3rd party libs for tagging. My needs are met with a simple autocomplete.

I will use a patch if its available.

Thank you

Comment: Not really clear what issue is. A demo in a code sharing site with sample of expected results might help

Comment: @charlietfl Not sure how to produce a working sample of what I need. When I start typing - it autosuggests tags from a local array. If i add a string not from this array and type comma ", " It will start suggesting again - I want this same functionality when I type space " "

Comment: keep in mind will likely break if terms have spaces in them. The delimiters are in the `split()` and `'join()` parts

Comment: hmm probably, but some items in the local array do have spaces in them and they seem to work fine. I think ill just add a "placeholder" attribute to the input "Add comma separated tags". graceful degradation? :(

Comment: they work now because the delimiter isn't a space, might work though